# Will a raycast or collider detect an unrendered mesh in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3d object (a capsule) that I'm using in lieu of a character model because the project is going to be from a first person perspective. You can choose in the inspector whether to render the object's mesh or not. Since this object is meant to be invisible and only a hitbox, I want to know if raycasts and colliders will still detect it. I'm assuming yes because the object seems to behave normally with the physics, but I want to avoid complications in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that matters for physics is the colliders and rigidbodies, It doesn't care about meshrenderers